# How to create bulk/batch processing action compatible for FOREACH Repeat mode 'Batch of items' in Workato

Tags: integration, ipaas, workato

In Workato when you add the FOREACH loop on any List, we can configure Repeat mode for that loop processing. Currently, in Workato we can select 'One item at a time' and 'Batch of item' values.
But to use 'Batch of items' we need actions that support batch/bulk processing. I am using custom action from a custom SDK connector.

So wanted to know how can I create a Custom bulk/batch processing action in Workato.

Comment: That actually depends on the type of operation you are doing in your SDK/Action, batch processing might be feasible if the SDK/webservice also accepts data in batches.

Comment: Yeah, my web service accepts data in batches.

Comment: does it accept it in a URL(like comma separated integers) or in some kind of JSON/XML body?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but you need to check whether target application supports the batch/bulk processing. If yes then you have to invoke the source system API with list of records.

Also, once that API is available then you can write connector SDK code. you can refer this documentation to create custom connector https://docs.workato.com/developing-connectors/sdk/sdk-reference.html.